# Rolling Dice Repeatedly

Tags: probability

This question is from DEGROOT's PROBABILITY and STATISTICS.

Rolling Dice Repeatedly:

Suppose that two dice are to be rolled repeatedly and the
sum $T$ of the two numbers is to be observed for each roll. We shall determine the
probability $p$ that the value $T =7$will be observed before the value $T =8$ is observed.

Solution:

The desired probability $p$ could be calculated directly as follows: We could assume that the sample space $S$ contains all sequences of outcomes that terminate as
soon as either the sum $T = 7$ or the sum $T = 8$ is obtained. Then we could find the
sum of the probabilities of all the sequences that terminate when the value $T = 7$ is
obtained.
However,there is a simpler approach in this example. We can consider the simple
experiment in which two dice are rolled. If we repeat the experiment until either the
sum $T = 7$ or the sum $T = 8$ is obtained, the effect is to restrict the outcome of the
experiment to one of these two values. Hence,the problem can be restated as follows:
Given that the outcome of the experiment is either $T = 7$ or $T = 8$, determine the
probability $p$ that the outcome is actually $T = 7$.
If we let $A$ be the event that $T = 7$ and let $B$ be the event that the value of $T$ is
either $7$ or $8$, then $A ∩ B = A$ and
$p = Pr(A|B) =Pr(A ∩ B)/
Pr(B)
=Pr(A)/
Pr(B)$.
But $Pr(A) = 6/36$ and
$Pr(B) = (6/36) + (5/36) = 11/36$. Hence, $p = 6/11$.

Now,my doubts are

1.) Why the author says "We could assume that the sample space $S$ contains all sequences of outcomes that terminate as
soon as either the sum $T = 7$ or the sum $T = 8$ is obtained. Then we could find the
sum of the probabilities of all the sequences that terminate when the value $T = 7$ is
obtained." ?

2.)How can we go from lengthy sequences of outcomes that terminate as
soon as either the sum $T = 7$ or the sum $T = 8$ is obtained to just the outcome of the experiment for which either $T = 7$ or $T = 8$ ?

Please help.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For 1, once you get either a $7$ or an $8$, you know the result of the run.  Any rolls we make subsequently will not affect the outcome, so we might as well ignore them.  As we roll $7$ or $8$ with probability $1$, to find the chance that a $7$ is last we just add them up.

2 is the more subtle point.  If you like thinking of Markov processes, we have one with just three states.  You have a start state and two ending states.  If you throw a $7$ you move to one end state.  If you throw $8$ you move to the other end state.  If you throw anything else, your return to start.  We are interested in the chance we end at $7$.  This is the chance of $7$ given that we threw either $7$ or $8$.  As the cycles back to start leave us in the same place, we can ignore them.

Comment: Sir, Marcov chains are explained in the book in later chapters, so how could the author use it before?(He has not presupposed it at all.)Will you please explain the second question with some other reasoning? Thanks.

Comment: Even so, the idea that if you throw something different from $7$ and $8$ you are back where you started should be clear.  You used to have to throw until you get one and you still have to throw until you get one.  All you care is the relative chance of $7$ and $8$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will you please elaborate why any rolls we make after 7 or 8 will not affect the outcome?

Comment: Because you already have the answer.  Once you get one, that is the first one you see, so it comes before the other.